# How to catch errors in Angular 6 resolvers?

Tags: angular, service, error-handling, resolver

I can't find any solution for my problem: How can I catch errors in Angular 6 if I'm using resolvers? My resolvers generally looks simple like that:

```
  resolve(activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.rs.getRessources(activatedRoute.queryParams['branch']);
  }
```

In the given services errors are already catched (by the service) - why this is not working while calling the service from a resolver; not from a component? Which is the best way to detect errors in the resolver **before** loading the component?

Thankful for any help

Comment: have u tried with RouterStateSnapshot??

Comment: and the best way to catch error is Intercepter.

Answer (score 1):

This resolver throws the errors if something went wrong before loading the component.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Initiative[]> {
    return this.actionItemService.getActionItems(route.params.id).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        this.alertifyService.error('Problem in resolving data');
        this.router.navigate(['/updateinitiative', route.params.id]);
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
```

This may be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the problem is elsewhere... The `ErrorHandler` of the service is called trouble-free by the resolver! My fault! **But**:

Inside the `ErrorHandler` I'm trying to navigate to an error page. That works fine if the service is used by a component and an error occures. If the service is used by a resolver there is no forwarding with `this.router.navigate(['/error']);` inside my `ErrorHandler`...

I think **thats** the real problem. But why?! How can I use `this.router.navigate(['/error']);` in the `ErrorHandler` while calling it from a resolver?

---

**Solution:**

After a long time I finally found the mistake. If someone else has a similar problem, here is my solution.

I forgot to throw an error with `return throwError(userMessage);` after forwarding in my `ErrorHandler`. Now `this.router.navigate(['/error']);` also works with resolvers.